# RecyclerView not populating with data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load recyclerview with data from SQLite database contents. But it is not working

This is what i have done

Activity class

```
public class ViewMembership extends AppCompatActivity {
private  RecyclerView recyclerView;
private  membership_view_recycler_adapter m;

private  DBHelper dbHelper;


public List<membership_recycler_model> membershipList=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_membership);
    dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.View_Membership_Recycler);
    m=new membership_view_recycler_adapter(membershipList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(m);

    prepare_membership();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
public void  prepare_membership()
{
    System.out.println("#######################Prepare_membership called");
    membershipList=dbHelper.membership_for_recycler_view();
   m.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

Adapter class

```
public class membership_view_recycler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<membership_view_recycler_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name,region;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.membership_name_textview);
        region=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.membership_region_textview);
    }
}


public membership_view_recycler_adapter(List<membership_recycler_model> membership_list) {
    this.membership_list = membership_list;
}

private List<membership_recycler_model> membership_list;



@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.membership_view_row,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    membership_recycler_model membership=membership_list.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(membership.getMembership_name());
    holder.region.setText(membership.getRegion());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return membership_list.size();
}}
```

I've got no compilation errors, application is not throwing any exceptions. dbHelper.membership_for_recycler_view() is returning appropriate values. I am kinda new in Android. I did this with the help of a tutorial. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you are calling `prepare_membership()`
function later and passing data to your adapter before with an empty list. Try to make following changes :

1. Add a new method in your adapter -

   ```
        public void refreshData(List<membership_recycler_model> membership_list){
             this.membership_list.clear();
             this.membership_list.addAll(membership_list);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
   ```
2. Inside your prepare_membership() function call this method after fetching the list from db i.e `m.refreshData(membershipList)`

```
`
```

Comment: will try that out.

Comment: I updated the answer to wipe the list that the Adapter was created with and populate it with the new items. The problem with assigning a new list is that if the list is modified outside of the adapter, those changes can be lost on re-assignment and `notifyDataSetChanged` might not work.